# how change type map mapbox-leaflet

Tags: leaflet, mapbox

I want type of map in a map that I create. I use leaflet and mapbob, but I dont know how change the type of map.

```
var mapboxTiles = L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tiles.mapbox.com/v3/examples.map-zr0njcqy/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: '<a href="http://www.mapbox.com/about/maps/" target="_blank">Terms &amp; Feedback</a>'
});
```

How I change the content tileLayer by one create for me?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

```
// Provide your access token
L.mapbox.accessToken = 'pk.yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy';
// Create a map in the div #map
L.mapbox.map('map', 'jonataswalker.kieo57jb'); //put yours here
```

Comment: I put this and I recive this error.  {"message":"Unauthorized"}. I put my token. What is the problem?

Comment: Did you change this `L.mapbox.map('map', 'jonataswalker.kieo57jb');` part?

Comment: Yes, I change the token and the map for my design. Need pay for open access map?

Comment: No, no payment! Are you using this: `<script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v2.1.9/mapbox.js'></script>
<link href='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v2.1.9/mapbox.css' rel='stylesheet' />`?

Comment: Yes, it was the problem. I use the version 1.6.x . Thank you very much!